# Use pdfsharp to extract individual pdf documents from a combined pdf document

Tags: pdfsharp

I am getting a pdf from a service where there are several pdf documents combined into that one pdf. I looked on the pdfsharp site and they talk about separating a pdf into individual pages. But I don't see where it can separate pdfs into their individual documents. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Simply, create a new `PdfDocument` for each document,  pull the page(s) you want  from the inputdocument  pages collection using indices and use `AddPage` .

Comment: For example, the combined pdf contains 2 documents, billofsale.pdf and inspection.pdf. Bill of sale has 5 pages and inspection has 3 pages. I would need to create 2 new pdf's and then pull the pages from the inputdocument and do an AddPage for each document. How will I know which pages are for which document?

Comment: If they are sent into order, that's easy pull them in order .. otherwise, you have to analyze the document content via image processing or OCR or any other technique

Comment: So there wouldn't be anything in metadata that would denote which pages go with with document?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible, or even if possible did the creator of the document add this meta-data .. that's the important question..
But I believe if all documents come from the same source, they will follow the same pattern..
And I believe documents are add to the pdf in order, so check it.